# telegram API sendAudio

Tags: go, telegram-bot

I can't send the audio correctly. I use this code:

```
func main() {
    botToken := "token"

    bot, err := telego.NewBot(botToken, telego.WithDefaultDebugLogger())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    updates, _ := bot.UpdatesViaLongPolling(nil)

    defer bot.StopLongPolling()

        //my package for getting audio parameters
    var m music.Music
    m.Authorization()

    for update := range updates {
        if update.Message != nil {
            chatID := tu.ID(update.Message.Chat.ID)

            //getting audio parameters
            params, err := m.GetAudioParams(update.Message.Text)
            if err != nil {
                _, _ = bot.SendMessage(&telego.SendMessageParams{
                    ChatID: chatID,
                    Text:   err.Error(),
                })
                continue
            }

            //link to download audio
            audio := tu.Audio(chatID, tu.FileByURL(params.URL))
            //filling performer
            audio.WithPerformer(params.Performer)
            //filling title
            audio.WithTitle(params.Title)

            _, _ = bot.SendAudio(audio)
        }
    }
}
```

I get such a debag response:

```
[Mon Apr 24 17:40:17 MSK 2023] DEBUG API call to: "https://api.telegram.org/botBOT_TOKEN/sendAudio", with data: {"chat_id":848447660,"audio":"https://s147iva.storage.yandex.net/get-mp3/bda9fda28fe66f5e3d4032b4a10bd888/0005fa16d2d871bc/rmusic/U2FsdGVkX19wkWz_DC4Mg4N6EoV332DXOynFrntt3AvzEYKgmcZd93n6fMrhy5u9Mcb7YcBr14nlkBrKxiEvJ2HXUM3AQ7RRFvxNXFkyYGU/575f1549004e4aa8ecc991e6696224e6af4248ddad339812300119ffbff2b6a8/27023","performer":"Performer","title":"Title"}
[Mon Apr 24 17:40:18 MSK 2023] DEBUG API response sendAudio: Ok: true, Err: [<nil>], Result: {"message_id":90,"from":{"id":6210745530,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"ya_music","username":"cleonia_music_bot"},"chat":{"id":848447660,"first_name":"\u0414\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0438\u043b","username":"Cleonia_21","type":"private"},"date":1682347218,"audio":{"duration":171,"file_name":"27023.mp3","mime_type":"audio/mpeg","file_id":"CQACAgQAAxkDAANaZEaU0qB2MyMvdaurhgOqYkDQdaoAAtsDAAIXTDVSLA0Gj1gWr_gvBA","file_unique_id":"AgAD2wMAAhdMNVI","file_size":4116480}}
```

Audio is sent to the user, but title and performer are not added. the audio is sent with the name and performer obtained from metadata or from data that was transmitted earlier when this file was first uploaded to the telegram server.(I don't know exactly)

I tried sending files that previously didn't exist in Telegram and didn't have title and performer set in metadata, and values were correctly used from those which I specified in the request.

How do I change title and performer in audio when sending?

Я использую Golang библиотеку https://github.com/mymmrac/telego

Comment: `audio := tu.Audio(chatID, tu.FileByURL(params.URL)).WithPerformer(params.Performer).WithTitle(params.Title)` try that